# Get the child node data from Json File

Tags: python, list, nodechildren

I got a list from JSON file, but how can I get the username and result from each result using Python?

Json File

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "abcde" : {
      "email" : "123@gmail.com",
      "gender" : "Male",
      "password" : "123",
      "result" : "Back Road Explorer",
      "username" : "abcde"
    },
    "halo" : {
      "email" : "halo@gmail.com",
      "password" : "halo",
      "result" : "Outdoor Adventure",
      "username" : "halo"
    },
    "01" : {
      "email" : "01@gmail.com",
      "gender" : "Male",
      "password" : "dajcaq",
      "result" : "Culinary Connoisseur",
      "username" : "01"
    }
}
```

The result should be:

```
username = abcde, halo, 01
result = Back Road Explorer, Outdoor Adventure, Culinary Connoisseur
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Take a look at the python's builtin [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json) module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json = {...}

result_username = []
result = []

for username in json['Users']:
    result_username += [username]
    result += [json['Users'][username]['result']]

print ('username : ',', '.join(result_username))
print ('result : ',', '.join(result))
```

**Result**

```
username :  abcde, halo, 01
result :  Back Road Explorer, Outdoor Adventure, Culinary Connoisseur
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like:

```
js = { 
    "Users": {
        "abcde": {
            "email": "123@gmail.com",
            "gender": "Male",
            "password": "123",
            "result": "Back Road Explorer",
            "username": "abcde"
        },
        "halo": {
            "email": "halo@gmail.com",
            "password": "halo",
            "result": "Outdoor Adventure",
            "username": "halo"
        },
        "01": {
            "email": "01@gmail.com",
            "gender": "Male",
            "password": "dajcaq",
            "result": "Culinary Connoisseur",
            "username": "01"
        }
    }
}

def parse_json(js):
    usernames, results = [], []
    for value in js['Users'].values():
        usernames.append(value["username"])
        results.append(value["result"])
    usernames, results = ', '.join(usernames), ', '.join(results),
    print(f'username = {usernames}')
    print(f'result = {results}')
```